# Creating a context menu with Rg.Plugins.Popup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

Is it possible to create a context menu using `Rg.Plugin.Popup`?

Basically, I would like to know if it is possible to do the following 2 things:

1. Disable the dimming effect around the pop-up
2. Place the pop-up adjacent to the button that is tapped in order to open it, above or bellow it.

Comment: Yes, these should be possible. Try using the BackgroundColor and SystemPaddingSides properties. Once you've shown what you've tried, you'll probably get more help from the community.

Comment: `BackgroundColor` indeed worked for removing the dimming effect! I set it to `Transparent`. Is there any example of `SystemPaddingSides` use?  I didn't find anything except a reference in the documentation that the property exists.

Comment: SystemPaddingSides was just a gut reaction based on a quick skim though the docs. Take a look at this thread for using translationX and Y to place the page: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/245#issuecomment-366625778